# Newline in Javascript for Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, return, newline

Example which is not working:

```
<div id="clockDisplay"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function renderTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var h = currentTime.getHours();
    var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var s = currentTime.getSeconds();
    setTimeout('renderTime()',1000);
    if (h < 10) {
        h = "0" + h;
    }
    if (m < 10) {
        m = "0" + m;
    }
    if (s < 10) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    var myClock = document.getElementById('clockDisplay');
    myClock.textContent = 'Local time:\n' + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    myClock.innerText = 'Local time:\n'+ h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}
renderTime();
</script>..
```

The --->  myClock.innerText = 'Local time:\n'+ h + ":" + m + ":" + s;  <---
separates Local time from the digits in Chrome.

However --->  myClock.textContent = 'Local time:\n' + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;  <---
is supposed to do the same just in Firefox but it doesn't work.

I have tried with    \n\r, \r\n, /\n/ and /\r/    Nothing worked for me..

Comment: `textContent` fails to show the newlines in all browsers, not just Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<br>` as line break. HTML collapses whitespace:

```
myClock.innerHTML = 'Local time:<br>' + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
```

Comment: Read again. It is in the top of the asker's question. It is a `<div>`.